# problem in writing subscript and superscript inside table

Tags: tables, subscripts, superscripts

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\caption{Optimal h}
\resizebox{9cm}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|*{9}{c|}}
\cline{1-9}
%\cline{1-1} \cline{9-10}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} \multicolumn{5}{|c|} P & \multicolumn{4}{|c|} P \\
\hline
 h & N\textsubscript{total} & Maj & Mean & $h\textsubscript{grid\_{pd}} & Maj & Mean &  $h\textsubscript{line\_{pfa}} & $h1$ \\
\hline
1 & 5 & 2 & 4.75 & 1 & 3 & 4.50 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
2 & 13 & 6 & 12.34 & 2 & 7 & 11.7 & 2 & 2\\
\hline
3 & 25 & 12 & 23.75 & 2 & 13 & 22.50 & 3 & 3\\
\hline
4 & 41 & 20 & 38.95 & 3 & 21 & 36.89 & 3 & 3\\
\hline
5 & 61 & 30 & 57.95 & 4 & 31 & 54.89 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
6 & 85 & 42 & 80.75 & 5 & 43 & 76.50 & 5 & 5\\
\hline
7 & 113 & 56 & 107.34 & 5 & 57 & 101.69 & 5 & 5\\
\hline
8 & 145 & 76 & 137.75 & 6 & 77 & 130.50 & 7 & 7\\
\hline
9 & 181 & 90 & 171.94 & 7 & 91 & 162.89 & 7 & 7\\
\hline
10 & 221 & 110 & 209.9 & 8 & 111 & 198.89 & 8 & 8\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In the code above on line 
`\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} \multicolumn{5}{|c|} P & \multicolumn{4}{|c|} P \\`
i want to write Pod with o as the superscript and d as subscript. But i am not able to do so..please help.

Comment: And never put in '$' in table in this way:
$A_i & B^2$ because '&' is the separator and it should not be within '$ $'.

Answer (score 1):

You text have more than one character, hence you should write

```
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{$P_d^o$} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{$\mathrm{P}_d^o$}  \\
```

etc. in the line in question. (Alternative variants shown).

Comment: $ sign italics text, that is undesired.

Answer (score 0):

This should work inside a table:

```
P$_{\texrm{d}}^{\textrm{o}}$
```

\textrm adds normal text in math mode